# Finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as completions of number fields with some valuation over a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

[In my first post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985141/understanding-the-derivation-of-the-p-adic-numbers-as-the-completion-from-ma), I asked if $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ over some valuation of an prime ideal (and it seems to be true, according to an answer). Now I am asking if this can be generalized for finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

To put it in other words: Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. **Question**: Is there a valuation $v$ of some prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_k$ on a global field $k$ (i.e. a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$) such that the completion $k_v$ of $k$ over $v$ is equal to $K$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is every finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ the completion of a number field at some valuation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888050/is-every-finite-galois-extension-of-mathbbq-p-the-completion-of-a-number-fi) This is true, but not completely straightforward. It follows from Krasner's lemma, which roughly says that the roots of nearby polynomials in $\mathbb Q_p[x]$ generate the same extension. So take the polynomial $f$ that generates $K$ and choose a nearby rational polynomial.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you for the link to the thread. Although the title seems to be really helpful, I cannot see in the linked post where exactly the valuation comes into play. It seems to not be included in the poster's description at all.

Comment: I forgot to add that I was interested in valuations wrt. prime ideals - I hope this does not confuse anyone.

Comment: There are also some linked mathoverflow posts in the comments? Completion with respect to valuations is completely standard terminology, so don't worry!

Comment: Did anyone try to show it from that $p$-adic Galois extensions [are solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification_group) ? Solvable means that once enough roots of unity are added the extension is contained in a radical extension and since $K^*/K^{*n}$ is easily shown finite depending solely on reduction data we get that these radical extensions are completions of number fields. For the subextensions we use the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

Comment: @reuns Is there a way to prove that $K^{\times}/K^{\times n}$ is finite without using Krasner's lemma? Without knowing that it's finite, I don't say why any given element should have a rational representative.

Comment: @Mathmo123 For $K$ a $p$-adic field, $1+p^2 O_K$  has finite index in $O_K^\times$ and $(1+p^2 O_K)^n = 1+p^{k+2} O_K$ where $p^k\| n$ so $(1+p^2 O_K)/(1+p^2 O_K)^n$ is finite and so are $O_K^{\times}/O_K^{\times n}$ and $K^{\times}/K^{\times n}$. If $K$ is the completion of a number field $F$ then $K^{\times}/K^{\times n}$  has representatives in $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$.  We want to show that there is a finite extension $F$ of $\mathbb Q$, and a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in the ring of integers $\mathcal O_F$ of $F$, such that $K$ is the completion of $F$ with respect to the $\mathfrak p$-adic valuation on $F$.

Krasner's lemma tells us that there is an irreducible polynomial $g(t)$ (irreducible in the ring $\mathbb Q_p[t]$, that is) with rational coefficients, and a root $\beta$ of $g(t)$, such that $K = \mathbb Q_p(\beta)$.  Then $g(t)$ is also irreducible in the ring $\mathbb Q[t]$, so if we set $F = \mathbb Q(\beta)$, then $[F : \mathbb Q] = [K : \mathbb Q_p] = \operatorname{deg} g$.

Now let $| - |$ be the unique extension of the $p$-adic absolute value to $K$.  Restrict $|-|$ to an absolute value on $F$.  A version of Ostrowski's theorem for number fields states that this absolute value is either archimedean, or arises from a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in the ring of integers $\mathcal O_F$ of $F$.  Specifically, there is a real number $0 < \rho < 1$ and a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ such that

$$|x| = \rho^{\operatorname{ord}_{\mathfrak p}(x)}.$$

Obviously this absolute value is not archimedean on $F$ (its restriction to the $p$-adic absolute value on $\mathbb Q$ isn't, after all).
Anyway, the completion of $F$ with respect to $\mathfrak p$ is the same as the metric space completion of $F$ with respect to $|-|$.  Finally, just as the metric space completion of $\mathbb Q$ with respect to $|-|$ gets you $\mathbb Q_p$, so does the metric space completion of $F = \mathbb Q(\beta)$ with respect to $|-|$ get you $\mathbb Q_p(\beta) = K$.